# Internal loop only runs once, containing loop runs endlessly

Tags: javascript, jquery

noob question I'm afraid.

I have a loop that runs and rotates the hand of a clock and an internal loop that checks the angle of the hand if it is 90, 180, 270 and 360. On these 4 angles the corresponding div is displayed and its siblings removed. The hand loops and loops eternally, which is what I want, but the angle check only runs the loop once through the whole 360. As the hand passes through the angles it is correctly displaying and removing divs but is doesn't continue after the first revolution of the clock.

I've obviously messed up somewhere and there is bound to be a more efficient way of doing all this. I am using jQueryRotate.js for  my rotations. Thanks for your time.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var angle = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        jQuery("#hand").rotate(angle);
        function movehand() {
            if (angle == 90) {
                jQuery("#intervention").fadeIn().css("display","block").siblings().css("display","none");
            } else if (angle == 180) {
                jQuery("#management").fadeIn().css("display","block").siblings().css("display","none");
            } else if (angle == 270) {
                jQuery("#prevention").fadeIn().css("display","block").siblings().css("display","none");
            } else if (angle == 360) {
                jQuery("#reaction").fadeIn().css("display","block").siblings().css("display","none");
            } else {
                movehand;
            }
        };
        movehand();
        angle+=1;
    },10);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once angle reaches 360 do you not need to reset it to 0?

http://jsfiddle.net/DHxBm/2/

Comment: I assumed it was already doing this. When I inspect the element the rotation appears to reset and start from 0 again rather than go 361, 362, etc.

Comment: Probably because the rotate function can't take an angle greater than 360 so it starts from 0, but the actual value of angle is going to 361, 362, etc and so none of the if statements are matched.

Comment: I've tried Gyan's solution to reset the angle to 0 bu that stops the angle check being run completely. I'll try to put a fiddle together and post it.

Comment: His solution is a bit broke. In your original code, add `ìf (angle > 360){ angle = 0; }` after `angle+=1;`and it should work.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with it running. It's speeded up just for testing purposes. http://jsfiddle.net/DHxBm/

Comment: @Mark Might be something to do with the jQuery rotate function (I don't know), but you could try doing `angle % 360 == x` in your if statements instead and it won't matter that the angle variable goes beyond 360.

Comment: Sorry Jonny but I can't get that to work either. Will keep trying. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DHxBm/3/ - as jonnyynnoj suggests, you need to set angle to 0 if it's greater than 360 :)

Comment: Brilliant Jonny, and the rest of you guys. Thanks. Can I ask if this is going to be very processor intensive. I will only be running on one of my pages and am wondering whether to include it at all on tablets and phones. Thanks.

Comment: About that JSFiddle, what is it supposed to be doing? For me it doesn't do anything visible on any of the angles in question, and I can see no difference between the first run and the next ones. Edit: The JSFiddle posted by jonnyynnoj looks identical to the original for me.

Comment: I would think any decent browser can handle it fine.

Comment: Hi Thor. The fiddle displays different divs based on the position of the hand of the clock. It's a mini slider of sorts, I suppose. Do the divs on the right hand side not change for you as the hand rotates?

Comment: @Mark Hmm. I see. For some reason the horizontal scrollbar wasn't showing, but there was content to the right (scrolling with mouse-wheel works). Ah well, at least it's not a bug with your JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var angle = 0;
setInterval(function(){
     jQuery("#hand").rotate(angle);
     function movehand(){
      if (angle == 90) {
      jQuery("#intervention").fadeIn().css("display","block").siblings().css("display","none");
    } else if (angle == 180) {
      jQuery("#management").fadeIn().css("display","block").siblings().css("display","none");
    } else if (angle == 270) {
      jQuery("#prevention").fadeIn().css("display","block").siblings().css("display","none");
    } else if (angle == 360) {
      jQuery("#reaction").fadeIn().css("display","block").siblings().css("display","none");
angle=0;
    } else {movehand;}
};

      angle+=1;
},10);
});
```